# SQLalchemy to get data from multiple table in single object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

I have 3 tables, **users**, projects and project_users **is_admin** table and I am trying to write ORM to get data from them.

My Models are here: https://pastebin.com/ZrmhKyNL

In simple SQL, we could join and select particular columns and get the desired output. But in ORM when I write query like this:

```
sql = """ select * from 
            projects p, users u, projects_users pu 
            where
            p.name = '%s' and
            p.id = pu.project_id and 
            pu.user_id = u.id and
            p.is_active = true and 
            u.is_active = true 
        """ % project_name
```

and it works well and returns response in this format:

[
{
All columns of above 3 tables.
}
]

But when I try to convert this to sqlalchamey ORM, it doesn't work well:

```
return (
        db.query(User)
        .filter(Project.id == ProjectsUser.project_id)
        .filter(ProjectsUser.user_id == User.id)
        .filter(Project.is_active == True)
        .filter(User.is_active == True)
        .filter(Project.name == project_name)
        .all()
    )
```

I want is_admin value to be returned along with user object. This seems very common use case, but I couldn't find any solution related to SQLalchemy ORM.

Comment: What is the FastAPI ORM? This looks like SQLAlchemy.

Comment: If it is SQLAlchemy, you could use relationships to accomplish this, and have a method on the `User` to return data in this format. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one

Comment: Sorry, I meant SQLalchemy only. Since I am writing this in Fast APi framework, I misunderstood with that.

Comment: I have relationship s defined. But not sure how I can achieve this. Also doucment doesn't seems to have any help regarding getting data from multiple tables.

Comment: Is it a one-to-one relationship ?

Comment: @EliasDorneles yes

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-to-one relationship, meaning that for every user you can have one and only one entry in the `admin` table, you could add a column to serve as back-reference:

```
class User(Base):
    id = ...
    name = ...
    last_login = ...
    admin = relationship("Admin", uselist=False, back_populates="user")

class Admin(Base):
    id = ...
    is_admin = ...
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="admin")
```

Then you can query only the table user, and access the values from the relationship via `user.admin.is_admin`.

### Read more:

- [One To One - SqlAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one)
- [`relationship.back_populates` - SqlAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates)

Comment: Hi Elias, this seems very close but somehow my use case is more complicated than this. I just updated with my exact requirement.

Comment: I am meanwhile trying to learn the documentation more